# How to use angular.forEach() in multi dimentional array or json

Tags: arrays, angularjs, json

I need to go through each text(parent and children)

Sample js code:

```
data: [
        { text: "Item 1" },
        { text: "Item 2", items: [
          { text: "SubItem 2.1" },
          { text: "SubItem 2.2" }
        ] },
        { text: "Item 3" }
      ]
angular.forEach(data, function (value, key) 
{
  console.log(value.text);
});`
```

This code only returned the parent texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It didn't work because you haven't looped on the child items. See the code below:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function() {
    var printItems = function(items) {
      angular.forEach(items, function(value, key) {
        console.log(value.text);

        if (value.items) {
          printItems(value.items);
        }
      });
    };

    var data = [{
      text: "Item 1"
    }, {
      text: "Item 2",
      items: [{
        text: "SubItem 2.1"
      }, {
        text: "SubItem 2.2"
      }]
    }, {
      text: "Item 3"
    }];
    
    printItems(data);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl"></div>
```

It extracts the logic to a separate function and calls it recursively to traverse the children.

Comment: Oh! My mistake is only the `function(v)` coz I used the same variable.
Thank you so much! Marked as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `angular.isDefined` to check the `items` property exist in each `data` object then loop through that to get the `text` value in `items` array:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  var data= [
    { text: "Item 1" },
    { text: "Item 2", items: [
      { text: "SubItem 2.1" },
      { text: "SubItem 2.2" }
    ] },
    { text: "Item 3" }
  ];
angular.forEach(data, function (value, key) 
  {
    console.log(value.text);
    if(angular.isDefined(value.items)){
      var itemsArray = value.items;
      angular.forEach(itemsArray, function (item, key){
        console.log(item.text);
      });
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl"></div>
```